# How to display pivot table derived from nested queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I have the following query:

First I need to fetch the default package IDs and the Roles for all the User Roles. Then, I need to fetch the operators and their margin rates for the corresponding package id.

Finally, I need to show role/package wise margin rates in separate columns in a pivot table.

Here's my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Operator</th>
        <th>Retailer Margin</th>
        <th>Distributor Margin</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        // Get the default Package IDs of all the roles
        $pdefault = 1;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT role,package FROM packages WHERE pdefault = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$pdefault);
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($role,$package);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            //Output

            //+-------------+-----------------+
            //| Role        | Default Package |
            //+-------------+-----------------+
            //| Retailer    | 1               |
            //+-------------+-----------------+
            //| Distributor | 2               |
            //+-------------+-----------------+

            // Get the margin rates of all the operators of all the default packages
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT operator, margin FROM margins WHERE package = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('i',$package);
            $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($operator,$margin);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            //Output

            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| Package  | Operator     | Margin   |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| 1        | Airtel       | 3.00%    |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| 1        | Idea         | 1.00%    |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| 1        | Vodafone     | 2.00%    |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| 2        | Airtel       | 4.00%    |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| 2        | Idea         | 2.00%    |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+
            //| 2        | Vodafone     | 3.00%    |
            //+----------+--------------+----------+ 


    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $operator ?></td>
        <td><!-- Retailer (Package ID 1) Margin here --></td>
        <td><!-- Distributor (Package ID 2) Margin here --></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } 
    } ?>

</table>
```

Final table should be like this:

```
    +------------+------------------+-------------------+
    | Operator   | Retailer Margin  | Distrbutor Margin |
    +------------+------------------+-------------------+
    | Airtel     | 3.00%            | 4.00%             |
    +------------+------------------+-------------------+
    | Idea       | 1.00%            | 2.00%             |
    +------------+------------------+-------------------+
    | Vodafone   | 2.00%            | 3.00%             |
    +------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

I think I'm doing above queries in a wrong way. I am not able to find out which way I could produce the desired table.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about you tables...

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

First do this:

```
SELECT p.package, p.role, m.operator, m.margin FROM packages p JOIN margins m ON m.package = p.package
```

Now you have a result containing the fields `package`, `role`, `operator`, `margin` of every package.

Now just output.

Comment: But how to represent the margin rates for Retailers and Distributors separately in the table columns?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two requests, use a single one with `join` closure.

```
"SELECT p.role, p.package, m.operator, m.margin FROM packages p join margin m on p.package = m.package "
```

Comment: But how to represent the margin rates for Retailers and Distributors separately in the table columns?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query fetch data for easily represent

```
  SELECT group_concat(p.role order by m.package),p.package, m.operator, group_concat(m.margin order by m.package) FROM packages p left join margin m on p.package=m.package WHERE pdefault = 1 group by m.operator;
```

Comment: But how to represent the margin rates for Retailers and Distributors separately in the table columns?

Comment: please explode role field value and margin field value both are same order if role 1st index is retailer then retailer column of table hold the value of 1st index of margin

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one query and then first collect the data in an associative, 2D array. Then iterate that array to produce the final table. You would also be able to dynamically create the titles of the margin columns. It would look something like this (untested):

```
<?php
$pdefault = 1;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT     m.operator, p.role, m.margin
    FROM       packages p
    INNER JOIN margins ON m.package = p.package
    WHERE      p.pdefault = ?
    ORDER BY   m.operator, m.package
");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $pdefault);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($operator, $role, $margin);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $roles[$role] = 1;
    $result[$operator][$role] = $margin;
}
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Operator</th>
<?php foreach($roles as $role => $ignore) { ?>
        <th><?=$role?> Margin</th>
<?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($result as $operator => $margins) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$operator?></td>
<?php    foreach($roles as $role => $ignore) { ?>
        <td><?=$margins[$role]?></td>
<?php    } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```